# HPUX large number conversion to avoid numbers like 2.13464e+07

Tags: awk, hp-ux

I need to divide 21858717696 by 1024 to get kilobytes on hpux, but using the command below does not work:

```
echo 21858717696 | awk '{print $1/1024}'
```

output:

```
2.13464e+07
```

On AIX I can use the below and it works:

```
echo 21858717696 | awk '{print $1/1024}' | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $1)}'
```

output:

```
21346404
```

Using the AIX method on HPUX does not work. How can I get the same result on HPUX?

Comment: Doesn't `echo 21858717696 | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $1/1024}'` work? If not, what does that output?

Comment: Define does not work. "Using the AIX method on HPUX does not work."

Comment: echo 21858717696 | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $1/1024}' does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just print the result from awk directly? You don't need the second awk there:

```
$ echo 21858717696 | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $1/1024}'
21346404
```

Unless I'm missing something, that's exactly the same as your second command:

```
$ echo 21858717696 | awk '{print $1/1024}' | bc -l | awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $1)}'
21346404
```

On my Linux system, I can only reproduce this using a much larger number and busybox awk:

```
$ echo 12321858717696000000000 | ./awk '{print $1/1024}'
1.20331e+19
```

But even with busybox awk, `printf` works as expected:

```
$ echo 12321858717696000000000 | ./awk '{printf "%.0f\n",$1/1024}'
12033065153999998976
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have perl on your HP-UX:

```
echo 21858717696|perl -ne 'printf "%.0f\n",$_/1024'
21346404
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `bc`:

```
$ printf '%s/1024\n' 21858717696 | bc
21346404
```

or

```
$ echo '21858717696/1024' | bc
21346404
```

or any other combination that lets `bc` do the calculation for you.  Include an assignment to `scale` if you want to set he number of decimals that you want (zero by default):

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'scale=4' '21858717696/1024' | bc
21346404.0000
```

The main thing is to let `bc` do the actual computation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it `dc <<< "21858717696 1024/ p"`

- I think `dc` in installed by default on nearly all Unixes. It wall on everything I have used since 1991.
- I is one process.
- It gives accurate and precise result.

If your shell does not do `<<<` then do

`echo "21858717696 1024/ p" | dc`